# Cut string from position to character

Tags: bash, shell, cut

I'd like to cut a string from a number of position until a specific character "/" :

It would cut this line :

```
Export text H8X7IS5G.FIC NB regs COLOLO 4138/4138
```

To this one :

```
4138
```

What i tried is to use cut -c with the position and the character but of course it doesn't work :

```
cut -c 57-'/'
```

Comment: Where does the number `57` come from?

Comment: The number 57 is the exact position of the beginning of the first number

Comment: But your line `Export text H8X7IS5G.FIC NB regs COLOLO 4138/4138` has 49 characters. There is no "57th position" in your line.

Comment: Oh okay, but i do not matters actually, as long as i can specify a number of position and a end character

Comment: You don't need `cut` for this at all -- you can do it all with bash builtins.

Comment: ...or, at least, you would be better off doing it all with bash builtins if you're doing it _just for one line_. If you're processing thousands of lines this way, then `cut` may actually be the right choice.

Comment: @YoussefHammouma, you're asking us to help you. It does matter, or else you're wasting our time.

Comment: I think you should back up a bit and explain the main issue you're trying to address; it sounds (to me) like you're looking to extract a specific pattern; you should describe the pattern you're looking for and skip the stuff about `cut` and `57` (as I'm assuming with different input strings you won't want to use a hard-coded `57`); better yet, provide a couple different input strings and the expected outputs for each string; you'll likely get a better/more-useful response if we know the main issue you're trying to address

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to stick with `cut` then this might be what you want:

```
echo 'Export text H8X7IS5G.FIC NB regs COLOLO 4138/4138' |
cut -c41- | cut -d/ -f1
```

There are many other ways to accomplish this task. If you have a `grep` which supports perl-compatible regular expressions, for instance, then I'd suggest something along this line:

```
grep -Po '.{40}\K[^/]*'
```

Or, a `sed` one-liner:

```
sed 's/.\{40\}//; s|/.*||'
```

Or, using pure `bash`

```
[[ $line =~ .{40}([^/]*) ]] && printf '%s\n' "${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're trying to process a single variable at a time (rather than a stream with hundreds or thousands of lines), you don't need `cut` for this at all.

```
input='Export text H8X7IS5G.FIC NB regs COLOLO 4138/4138'
result=${input:40}
echo "${result%%/*}"
```

...emits `4138`.

Both `${var:start:len}` (and its shorter synonym `${var:start}`) and `${var%%PATTERN}` are examples of [parameter expansion](https://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pe) syntax; the former takes only a subset of a string starting at a given position; the latter trims the longest possible match of `PATTERN` (`${var%PATTERN}` trims the *shortest* possible match of `PATTERN` instead).

These and other string manipulations in bash are also documented in [BashFAQ #100](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/100).